# mostrar el sueldo máximo, mínimo y la media de los sueldos digitados

Tags: python-3.x

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

> Realizar un programa que permita pedir un número N, introducir los N sueldos,      y mostrar el sueldo máximo, mínimo y la media de los sueldos digitados. Se debe validar que los sueldos sean valores positivos.

He intentado de esta manera, pero no cuadra, haciendo una lista, pero se me dificulta sacar el promedio y el máximo y mínimo juntos, solo puedo 1.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Ingrese la cantidad de sueldos:")
    n = int(input())
    acum = 0
    list: []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print("El valor de los sueldos de cada persona")
    dato = float(input())                           
    acum = acum + dato
    prom = acum / n

    print("#####################")  
    print("El sueldo mas bajo es:", acum3)
    print("#####################")
    print("El sueldo mas alto es:", acum2)
    print("#####################")  
    print("El promedio de los sueldos de las ", n, "personas son:", prom)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español! Por favor, visita nuestro [tour], solo toma 1 minuto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograr eso usando las funciones `min()`, `max()` t `sum()` y `len()` en listas.

- `min(lista)` retorna el valor más bajo en la lista.
- `max(lista)` retorna el valor más alto en la lista.
- `sum(lista) / len(lista)` retorna la división entre la suma de todos los valores de la lista y la cantidad de valores que posee (básicamente obtiene un promedio).

No te olvides de insertar los sueldos en tu lista de sueldos, usando el método `lista.append(valor)`.

El código sería:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Ingrese la cantidad de sueldos:")
    n = int(input())
    sueldos = [] # No se usa ":" para asignar valores como hiciste en tu pregunta. Además nombrar una variable "list" sobrescribe la función list(), por lo tanto, aqui la nombre sueldos.
    for _ in range(n): # No es necesario usar 1, n + 1
        print("El valor de los sueldos de cada persona:")
        sueldos.append(int(input()))            
    print("#####################")  
    print("El sueldo mas bajo es:", min(sueldos))
    print("#####################")
    print("El sueldo mas alto es:", max(sueldos))
    print("#####################")  
    print("El promedio de los sueldos de las ", n, "personas son:", sum(sueldos) / len(sueldos))
```

Pero además tu consigna pedía comprobar que los valores sean positivos, algo que no hiciste, no se también era parte de la pregunta del OP pero aquí dejo una solución a eso. Simplemente reemplaza el `for` con:

```
while len(sueldos) < n:
    print("Introduzca el sueldo de la", n + 1, "º persona. El valor debe ser un número positivo")
    try:
       valor = float(input())
    except ValueError:
       print("Eso no es un número!")
    else:            
        if valor <= 0:
            print("Ese valor no es positivo!")            
        else:
            sueldos.append(valor)
```

Antes que saber si el número es positivo o negativo debemos saber si es un número, para eso esta el `try` donde intentamos convertir el `string` del `input` en un número. En caso de fallar (`ValueError`), se avisa al usuario de que no es un número, en caso correcto se procede a comprobar si en negativo.

Comment: Muchas gracias , que genial !